# Initialize a queue of addresses

Tags: c++, arrays, queue

How would you initialize a queue that will be filled with the address of cells in a 2d array?

If my 2d array is: `int a[3][3]`

Would the queue just be:

```
queue int* myQueue ?
```

Comment: Start with [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). Then look at [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: No because `queue int*` doesn't seem a valid syntax unless `queue` or `int` is a macro. One possibility is `queue<int*> myQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the queue as:

```
queue<int*> myQueue;
```

Then go on to filling it by doing something like this:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 3;++i){
    for(int j = 0;j < 3;++j){
        myQueue.push_back(&a[i][j]);
    }
}
```